# Making campaigns tracking in Piwik

Tags: analytics, web-analytics, matomo

I'm newbie in Piwik.

[I read this](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-campaigns/) but didn't understand how to use campaigns in Piwik.

Can anyone describe me or give me an example how to use campaigns tracking in Piwik?

Answer (score 1):

You can't track campaigns with piwik if no campaign is running for your website. Campaigns refer to payed adverts that are leading to your site. If you have such campaigns running you have to use the UTM parameters send by google, bing or which ever ad provider you use.

If you want to track specific events on your website like click on an ad or call of a specific tool I recommend the use of [piwik goal tracking](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-goals-web-analytics/).

Comment: Thanks for good guidance. see i have this link for each Ad `index.php/view/[ad_id]`, how can track each Ad. can give me an simple example. Very thanks.

Comment: this would lead to another question and furthermore it would be outside the box. I recommend you to read to piwik manual. It is very nice and expressive. In general it should answer all your questions